# How to Write springRset CRUD in @RestController class with entity relation like OneToOne etc, Not with springBoot, thanks

Tags: hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

I just want to know how to write springRset CRUD in @RestController class with entity relation like OneToOne etc,

Below is the google drive link for my file,

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1anxgLsKvrd5FtMqtTWAJDM_j6hPzG2Yk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, I think you can checkout these blogs : 

1. https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

2. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships

You can refer these blogs and prepare entities. If error or exception comes, then you can update that info here. I think that will be fast. :)

Comment: I appreciate for your replay , But Your Answer not meet with the Question bro. In above Question i asked for springRest CRUD inrestController (@RestController) class with entity relationship, Not just OneToOne and OneToMany,

Comment: I checked your project and your exposing your entity objects over REST... I would prefer using DTO objects rather than entity/domain objects.
you can refer one of my github same project : https://github.com/sagar-rout/user-mgmt-api

I think you are asking more about best practices.... if you are facing any issue... I think you should put your error or exception that will be the best. To be honest I think reviewing complete code base would be too much.